# want to play media a mp3 with imagebutton in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to play a mp3 with ImageButton in Fragment.
here is my code:
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

```
View myView;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
    return myView;

    ImageButton btn  = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.paratha);

    //on click button for paratha
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer paratha = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.paratha);

            paratha.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nextscreen()` method should looks like that:

```
public void  nextscreen() {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

You want to make intent but you need transaction to load you second fragment.

Comment: Once again thank you very much sir. appreciate for your help. its working now.

Comment: Please be correct and vote up my answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You set your click listener below return statement. This is wrong, also the context should be `getActivity()` instead `this` in `MediaPlayer`, because you use `fragment` not an `activity`. Change your method like that:

```
    View myView;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

        ImageButton btn  = (ImageButton)myView.findViewById(R.id.paratha);

        //on click button for paratha
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer paratha = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.paratha);

                paratha.start();
            }
        });

        return myView;
    }
```

Hope it help!

Comment: i want to add a next screen screen activity after completion media player. could you tell me the method in fragment. thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand clearly. Please explain me what exactly do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

i want to move next screen, after mediaplayer finished the audio.

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

```
View myView;
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton btn;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

    btn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.paratha);

    //on click button for paratha
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer paratha = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.paratha);
            paratha.start();

            paratha.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    nextscreen();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return myView;
}

public void  nextscreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondFragment.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

MainActivity file is here:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FirstFragment())
                .commit();
                        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

second_layout xml file:
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

```
View secView;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    secView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, container, false);
    return secView;
}
```

}

Comment: I understood, but please post your `MainActivity.class` and it's xml file to give you corret answer.

Comment: here is the main activity file and SecondFragment file. tell me which xml file you want.